# What it means to have body in delegates declaration?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

I have just seen following code:

```
class X
{
  static Action Ac()
  {
     return ..some other code
  }
}
```

What does it mean? I have never seen a delegate with its body declared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not an `Action` delegate with its body declared. That's a static method of the `X` class called `Ac()`, with a return type of `Action`; that is, it's a class method that returns an `Action` delegate. The body presumably creates an `Action` object to return from the method.

To put it another way: it is a regular static method, which happens to return `Action` instead of something like `string` or `int`.

Comment: :) Thanks, I did not realize its that simple

Answer (score 0):

Delegate object which references anonymous method is declared something like (using old syntax and omitting lambda notation):

```
Action<int> action = delegate (int x) { 
                        //this is a body of anonymous method
                        //which is referenced by a delegate object action of type Action<int>
                        Console.WriteLine (x);
                        };
```

And than called like:

```
 action(5);
```